# Sending message from udp client to udp server without sending protocol address of client

Tags: udp

I have a query is it possible to send data from udp client to udp server without sending the protocol address and then from server to client

Server.c

```js
if(bind(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0){
        printf("Couldn't bind to the port\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Done with binding\n");
    
    printf("Listening for incoming messages...\n\n");
    
    // Receive client's message:
    if (recvfrom(socket_desc, client_message, sizeof(client_message), 0,
         (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL) < 0){
        printf("Couldn't receive\n");
        return -1;
    }
    // printf("Received message from IP: %s and port: %i\n",
    //        inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
    
    printf("Msg from client: %s\n", client_message);
     
    // Respond to client:
    int n = atoi(client_message);
    int m =0, sum = 0;
      while(n>0){    
        m=n%10; 
        sum=sum+m;    
        n=n/10;    
    }  
    sprintf(server_message, "%d", sum); 
    
    if (sendto(socket_desc, server_message, strlen(server_message), 0,
         (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, client_struct_length) < 0){
        printf("Can't send\n");
        return -1;
    }
```

When I send data from client to server the server printed what I had sent from client but then then when I tried to send data back to client it is unable to send the modified data.

Comment: `client_addr` does not magically get filled with the clients address. It has to be explicitly done in `recvfrom` - but you use instead `NULL` there and thus throw away this information.

Answer (score 0):

`client_addr` does not magically get filled with the clients address. It has to be explicitly done in `recvfrom` - but you use instead `NULL` there and thus throw away this information:

> ```
> if (recvfrom(socket_desc, client_message, sizeof(client_message), 0,
>      (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL) < 0){
> ```